# My ul menu, with links attached to the li tags, won't stack horizontally but goes vertical instead

Tags: css, menu, zurb-foundation

Using foundations menu (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html) I'm having the problem that adding links to the li tags means the menu is no longer horizontal but vertical. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="li1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <a href="#"><li class="li3">Products</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="li4">Services</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="li5">Contact</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a snippet with relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
.specific-li-class{
    display: inline;
}
```

For completeness and as mentioned by [Jan P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5986007/jan-p), the code with the `a` tags in the right position

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="li1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="li3"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li class="li4"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="li5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks guys, but I guess my question then is how to I get the li itself to be clickable and not just the text inside of it? That was my purpose for linking the li itself.

Comment: no the actual background itself.

(sorry I clicked enter by accident)

I've added padding to the li classes like so:

    .li1 {
 background-color:#22a7ef; 
 padding: 6em 2em 0em 2em;
   }

Comment: Put padding on the anchor tag instead of the li. On the anchor add: display:block; then add padding to that.

Comment: If you could have another look at that codepen, the trouble is I want the buttons to have heights and widths and when I encapsulate the link over the text alone it doesn't fit the width and height of the parent div - in this case an li tag. Appreciate the help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, it is not allowed to have `a` as direct children of `ul`. Your code MUST be like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 columns">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="li1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="li3"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li class="li4"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="li5"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```